# Why is null not written to output window?

Tags: c#, null, output

z contains NULL. Why doesn't the output window show the NULL? Is it because NULL is not a value?

```
int? x = null;
int? y = 1;
int? z = 0;
z = x + y;
Debug.WriteLine(z);
```

[image: Output window does not show null]

Comment: What would that look like exactly?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine((object)z ?? "null");`

Comment: Thank you Olivier. I actually wanted to know why the output doesn't display null. Just curious.

Comment: Use [the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceListener.cs,4d1f8e907e0dadaf), Luke.

Comment: It's like asking someone to give an answer to a question you haven't asked.  The answer doesn't exist, how could it be *said*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you look into the [reference source of `Console.WriteLine(Object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,17999987f8ff4399), you can see that .NET calls `System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(Object)` which does explicitly check for `null` and will then output a blank line:

```
public virtual void WriteLine(Object value) {
    if (value==null) {
        WriteLine();
    }
    else {
        // Call WriteLine(value.ToString), not Write(Object), WriteLine().
        // This makes calls to WriteLine(Object) atomic.
        IFormattable f = value as IFormattable;
        if (f != null)
            WriteLine(f.ToString(null, FormatProvider));
        else
            WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

[`Debug.WriteLine(Object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/Debug.cs,de18340cbf015ef1) behaves the same way but is a bit more complicated. It eventually calls [`System.Diagnostics.TraceListener.WriteLine(Object)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceListener.cs,4d1f8e907e0dadaf).

Comment: Basically the answer is because the implementors decided NULL is converted to an empty string in the case of `int?.ToString()`.

Comment: You are correct, it prints a blank line. I hadn't noticed that. I would have thought it would print NULL, because when I debug the value of z, it shows null. At the same time null is not a value, so I guess it makes sense for output to not show it.

Comment: YMMV.  Try the same thing with `String a = null;Debug.WriteLine(a);`.  Beware the `virtual`.